# mod-rewrite with flask, wsgi, and Apache 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently hosting a flask-web app on a server with ip address (say 1.2.3.4).  I have Apache2 as my web server, connecting to flask using wsgi.  There are currently multiple applications running on the same server so I have set up virtual hosts in apache to map each app to a specific port.

I am currently trying to redirect a domain name to the server.  For slightly annoying reasons beyond my control, I have to do the redirect through the .htaccess file on the server currently pointed to by the domain.  So www.example.com/app gets redirected to 1.2.3.4:8080.

Now, I would like to rewrite the URLs so that instead of seeing 1.2.3.4:8080/home after the redirect, users see www.example.com/app/home.

How would I go about doing it?  Can I add a .htaccess file somewhere in the flask directories?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ned to use a reverse proxy to do this, and you'll only be able to do this if mod_proxy is loaded on the server hosting the `www.example.com` domain. From htaccess, you can create a rule and use the `P` flag to reverse proxy. If mod_proxy isn't loaded, this rule won't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ http://1.2.3.4:8080/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Quick question, do I add this to the htaccess file on the server hosting www.example.com or the one hosting 1.2.3.4?

Comment: @user2874557 I said to put it in the `www.example.com` domain. The htaccess file in the document root.